# Why can't I change UITableViewCell's ContentView after initiation

Tags: uitableview, setcontentview

I am able to add a 'line separator' above my uitableviewcells manually (out-of-box iOS isn't cutting it for this). So I have created an array of UIViews, called _separatorLines, I add one UIView from each index to the uitableviewcells' contentView in my 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' with

```
  UIView *v         = [_separatorLines objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:v];
```

however when i select a cell, i would like all other cells' line separators to turn red.
 in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' I have:

```
{
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _rowsInSection-1; i ++)
{
  //make all other rows have a red content view
  if(i != indexPath.row)
  {
            NSIndexPath *I = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:I];

            UIView *separatingLineView = [_separatorLines objectAtIndex:I.row+1];
            separatingLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:separatingLineView];
            [separatingLineView setNeedsDisplay];

            [cell setNeedsDisplay];
            [cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];
        }
    }

  [self setNeedsDisplay];
```

Instead I do not see the contentView of the uitableviewcells changing.

Answer (score 0):

For me I think the issue was the line
    NSIndexPath *I = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i **inSection:1];**

UITableView starts on section '0' (just like the rows start on '0').

And also because my UITableView is the delegate, I stopped using

```
[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:I];
```

and replaced it with

```
[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:I];
```

Not sure if that had anything to do with it